# How to navigate to dynamical path using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a route that matches this pattern:

```
MyDll.<major>.<minor>.<bug_fix>/internal_lib/version/files_i_need_to_get
```

I'm trying to navigate to the **files_i_need_to_get**, ignoring `<major>`, `<minor>`, `<bug_fix>`, and copy all containing .dlls to another folder. So I wrote this:

```
xcopy /e origin\MyDllFolder.*\lib\v40\*.dll lib\packages
```

But *MyDllFolder.** seems to not be working as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from the command line:

```
for /d %F in ("origin\MyDllFolder.*") do @xcopy /e "%F\lib\v40\*.dll" lib\packages
```

Double up the percents if used in a batch script:

```
for /d %%F in ("origin\MyDllFolder.*") do xcopy /e "%%F\lib\v40\*.dll" lib\packages
```

Comment: What do you mean with double up? As I'm using a batch script and it's not currently working.

Answer (score 1):

XXcopy has wildcard features that will do what you want.  http://www.xxcopy.com

Comment: `xxcopy /e "C:\origin\MyDllFolder*\lib\v40\*.dll" "d:\lib\packages\"` <--- try a command like that - it is xcopy compatible mostly.  You may need to use `xxcopysu` as the command which doesn't use admin permissions and works under a standard user (su).

Comment: More or less it works, but it also copies the folder. I only want the .dlls.

Comment: Regular xcopy would copy the folders too, but `XXcopy` has a flatten directory feature so you can use that.  You must consider any filename clashes.